# Global donations via PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a script that collects donations from people on company website, I am able to get the PayPal integrated with our system and able to get the donations work as well, however if someone does not have a paypal account they try to pay via Credit Card (at PayPal) but they get into the problem where no matter what country they select the states dropdown never changes, here is what my `form` looks like. I was wondering if i need to send something with my form to accept global donations, which might eventually solve the problem with states dropdown.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> \
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick-subscriptions"/> \
    <input id="business" name="business" type="hidden" value="'+loadEmail()+'"/> \
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Donation to One Horizon"/> \
    <input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="aid-donation"/> \
    <input id="currency_code" name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="'+loadCurrency()+'"/> \
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1"/> \
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://onehorizon.net/index.php/thank-you-for-your-donation/"/> \
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden"
           value="http://onehorizon.net/index.php/thank-you-for-your-donation/?error=cancel"/> \
    <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1"/><input name="lc" type="hidden" value="CA"/> \
    <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF"/>';
    <input type="submit" class="mcpddonatenow" name="submit" value="Donate Now" alt=""> \
</form>
```

[image]

I have been searching online and into the PayPal documentations but could not find out what seems to be the problem, i will really appreciate if i can get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like something you'd have to post to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts), but you're going to need to provide as much detail as possible.

Try clearing your browser history/cache and re-trying it.  Also try different browsers to see if the problem is happening only in a single browser or version.  You need to try and narrow it down to a single browser/version that it might be happening in.

Really, though, emptying your history/cache might actually fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @andrew, got a reply from paypal that i need to contact MTS